# Does Linux automatically close files?

Tags: c, linux, dirent.h

I'm creating a scheduling software, i have hundreds of dataset described in text files.
I'm using dirent.h with a loop to read the texts files, for each file i make a schedule and i append the result to another text file ( like cpu time, dataset name, tardiness ...), this file is common to all schedules.

I'm opening/closing the result file just once ( `fopen()` before the loop, `fclose()` after the loop when all the schedules are done).

I've no problem on Windows 7, but under linux, the file seems to be closed by the system due to a kind of timeout, I've just 9-10 dataset that are scheduled (~ 2 hours) and after it is stuck because it can't write into the result file :/

Does anyone already have this kind of trouble and found a solution?

Comment: "*it can't write into the result file*" giving which error (value for `errno`)?

Comment: Why do you think the file is closed?. BTW when you use `fopen` you should use `fclose` not `close`, it would not compile anyway if it does compile then turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: sorry i've missed the "f", it's fclose of course :)

Comment: @DanIdle Ok, but you did not answer my question. I will ask it again What makes you think the file is closed? Just a write error?

Comment: I've no error, that's the problem, it stopped after 2 hours, without saying anything, the result is not written into the file, under windows i haven't the same problem, i'm just using standard C libs. I've run it many times, at each try it has stopped arount 2 hours

Comment: Maybe `fopen()` failed (for instance: because you omitted the path) and you did not check the result of `fopen()` in line#42

Comment: i open the result file just once, so i can't have omitted the path, the results of the first schedules are well written, then another dataset is open, the content is printed into the terminal, it never ends and the result is not written into the result file.

Comment: Finally , it's due to a syntax problem in one of the input text files, bug the reaction to the bug is different between linux and windows, under windows it skips the corrupted file, on linux it blocks. I'll try to understand why !

Answer (score 1):

Linux does not close the file automatically. Something is wrong in your code.

Try running your program using "strace" and identify where the `close()` happens.

```
strace -f -o 1.txt ./my_best_app_ever
```

Open the `1.txt` file using a text editor (or `less`) and see what your app is doing.

Comment: i'll try soon thanks, but i don't understand why there is no problem under Windows ... I'm just using arrays and dirent to read dirs, fopen()/fclose() to read the datasets and write into the result file. It's just standard C code, without something special :/

Comment: well it's actualy running with strace :) let's see what will happened within 2 hours

Comment: Keep in mind that strace might reduce the performance of your app, so if you are doing something multithreaded, and you are missing a lock or something, things might miss-behave. I assume this is not valid for your scenario - but someone else might read it and learn.

Comment: you're right, there is just one thread, but i'll keep it in my mind for the future !